# Doctrine queryBuilder: return object not array

Tags: php, symfony, object, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have this query created with doctrine querybuilder, the return i get is an array of arrays.
I would like to get a return that is an array of objects, is this possible?

I know that normally Doctrine returns objects of an entity, bit since i have an inner join to get the name from another table it returns arrays.

Thanks in advance.

```
   $qb->select('u', 'h.name')
        ->from('AppBundle:UserHose', 'u')
        ->innerJoin('AppBundle:Hose', 'h', 'WITH', 'u.hoseId = h.id')
        ->where('u.userId = :userId')
        ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('userId', $userId); 


    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible this way. In other words, you are doing it wrong.

You are telling Doctrine to return a collection of collections containing an entity and a string so this is what you get. Doctrine won't make an object out of that since it does not know how to hydrate such result.

```
[
  [entity, string],
  [entity, string],
  ....
]
```

If you wish to receive a collection of objects only, you would need to create a new entity that has both fields (related entity and a string property), then use a [ResultSet mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) to hydrate that.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this:

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Or this:

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want array of objects you have to set relation betwen Entities, and create a query by the owning side of relation.

example:

```
Tourney entity , Invite entity

Invite
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tourney", inversedBy="invites")
     */
    protected $tourneys;

Tourney
    /**

     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Invite", mappedBy="tourneys", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $invites;
```

now you have to make query to the owning side of relation (Invite)
and it will be holding all your join object data with Tourneys in field $invites

**and it gives you array of objects.** based on your query

remeber of setter $invites as setInvites(Tourney $invites) and by inverse side of relation setTourneys(Invite $tourneys)

Answer (score -2):

Just add `\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` on `getResult()` like this

```
$qb->select('u', 'h.name')
   ->from('AppBundle:UserHose', 'u')
   ->innerJoin('AppBundle:Hose', 'h', 'WITH', 'u.hoseId = h.id')
   ->where('u.userId = :userId')
   ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC')
   ->setParameter('userId', $userId); 

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Might want to read the question a bit closer.  He is already getting an array result for some reason.  He want an array of objects.